# JQGrid - Event grid complete just for the "first time"/Apply default filter first loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using JQGrid (jQuery jQgrid not Gurrido) version 4.6.0 and I need an event that is launched only the first time the grid is complete. I tried `loadComplete` and `gridComplete` but it seems that both do more or less the same thing (they are both launched every time I filter/paging the grid).

I would like to apply a default filter when the page is loaded for the first time. I wrote this code for filtering the grid :

```js
f.rules.push({field: "ETAT_PROJ_",op:"eq",data:projOver})
grid[0].p.search = true
$.extend(grid[0].p.postData,{filters:JSON.stringify(f)});
grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1,current:true}]);
```

But I can't find the event to execute it.
I have also tried this:

```js
$().ready(function() {
 var f = {groupOp:"AND",rules:[]};
 f.rules.push({field: "ETAT_PROJ_",op:"eq",data:projOver})
 grid[0].p.search = true
 $.extend(grid[0].p.postData,{filters:JSON.stringify(f)});
 grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1,current:true}]);
})
```

I try also to apply the filter directly in the definition of my `colModel` with the searchoption attribute :

```js
{name: "ETAT_PROJ_", hidden: true,search:true,searchoptions:{dataInit:1, attr:{title:1}}},
```

And also this in the grid definition :

```
search: true,
postData: {'filters': '{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"ETAT_PROJ_","op":"eq","data":"1"}]}'},
```

But nothing work as i want (i still have all my data when the grid is loading the first time) but when i do an action (like paging for example) the filter is applied...

**EDIT - Example of solution**

After some research i find a way to apply a default filter in the first load. It's surely not the best approach to do that but this is the only way that i found. :)

```js
setTimeout(function() {
   grid = $("table#jqGrid-table-projets");
   console.log("load default filter")
   f = {groupOp:"AND",rules:[]}
   f.rules.push({field:"ETAT_PROJ_",op:"eq",data:"1"});
   grid[0].p.search = true
   $.extend(grid[0].p.postData,{filters:JSON.stringify(f)});
   grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1,current:true}]);
}, 1500)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very important to specify the version used - not only version 4.
There is a jqGrid version 4.x, Guriddo jqGrid ver 4.x and the fork free-jqGrid ver 4.x. All these have difference in some definitions and events.

Anyway there is a very simple solution. The idea is:

1.Set a global flag (let say) to true.

2.In your gridComplete or loadComplete check if this flag is true and if yes run your code.

3.After your code set this flag to false

```
var run_me_once = true;
...
$("#grid").jqGrid({
...
    gridComplete :function() {
        if(run_me_once) {
            // here your code
            run_me_once = false;
        }
    }
});
```

More precisely, you can remove the gridComplete event after first run, but this will do the job

Comment: Your way to do the event works great, but it seems that the ```reloadGrid``` function don't work in this case, because the grid is not reloading with the filter apply... Don't know why

Comment: do you have an idea ?

Comment: EDIT : In fact it work, but still not as i want. When i load the page i have all the datas (not filtered as i want) but when i do an action that trigger ```gridComplete``` event, the filter is apply...What I want is to filter the grid directly when the page is loading in fact. There is still a problem with the event...

Comment: There is no problem with the event, These events works after the grid loads the data and not before as you want. Which  version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: Ah yes indeed. i thought the grid must have been launched totally to filter it but maybe filtering before the grid load is better. I'm gonna try this. I'm using jQuery jQGrid version 4.6.0

Comment: I try with ```beforeProcessing``` and that's not work too... Is there a way to apply default filter when the grid is loading ?

Comment: Versin 4.6 is six years old and I can confirm some functionalities. With the last version of Guriddo using our PHP component we have example [Search upon loading](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/demos/jqgrid/searching/search_dynamic/default.php) which do what you want. If you have difficulties to understand the code I will try to prepare  example in pure JavaScript

Comment: The problem is that i have to change every grid that i have already develop, and moreover it's not free... I have find a way to do want i want, i put the code in my first post. I don't if this is the best solution, but it work

Comment: The solution is not perfect, but if it works it is ok. Just to note that in this case you do two request to the server - the initial when the grid loads and the other set with setTimeout. Note that in case you have a relative big data loading or there is a problem with loading data - setTimeout interval should be big. I think that you first solution should work too (which is the preferred) - i.e when you set postadata direct in grid options. Maybe you will need to check your code carefully in this case.

Comment: Even with the property ```loadOnce``` set to true ? I thought the json was load one time and after that the grid manage the data to display (so for me it's just 1 request to the server) ...? But yeah i know that this is not the best solution. Currently i got 200 datas displayed but indeed it could be interesting to test with more datas....